# Prolog convert integer to bytes

Tags: binary, numbers, prolog, format

I am using SWI prolog. I would like to write integers into binary file in binary form. I did not found any solution so far and starting to be desperate. Can any body help me with this problem?

Comment: Would this be 32 bit integers? What byte ordering do you expect? For example, do you output 0xFFEEAABB as `0xFF, 0xEE, 0xAA, 0xBB` (most significant byte first) or `0xBB, 0xAA, 0xEE, 0xFF` (least significant byte first)?

Comment: Yes, 32b integers little endian output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I used SWI Prolog.

I couldn't see anything that would write a number in a binary form in the built in libraries, but you could try and write your own.

The following only works on numbers from 0 to 4294967295 inclusive (an unsigned 32-bit int) and will output the number in 4 bytes, least significant byte first.

If you run "test", it will create a 4 byte file called "byte.dat", write the number, then read it again and print it out...

```
doWrite(FileName, Number) :-
    open(FileName, write, O, [all(true), encoding(octet)]),
    writeInt32(O, Number),
    close(O).

doRead(FileName, Number) :-
    open(FileName, read, I, [all(true), encoding(octet)]),
    readInt32(I, Number),
    close(I).

writeInt32(OS, Number) :-
    B0 is Number /\ 255,
    B1 is (Number >> 8) /\ 255,
    B2 is (Number >> 16) /\ 255,
    B3 is (Number >> 24) /\ 255,
    put_byte(OS, B0),
    put_byte(OS, B1),
    put_byte(OS, B2),
    put_byte(OS, B3).

readInt32(IS, Number) :-
    get_byte(IS, B0),
    get_byte(IS, B1),
    get_byte(IS, B2),
    get_byte(IS, B3),
    Number is B0 + B1<<8 + B2<<16 + B3<<24.

test :-
    doWrite('byte.dat', 3287465),
    doRead('byte.dat', X),
    write(X).
```

SWI prolog allows arbitrary length numbers, which is probably why there is no "write number as binary" in the standard libs.

I hope this helps, if anyone knows of a nicer way of doing this, please let us know!

Comment: Thank you very much! I hoped in some hidden built-in fuctionality, but this should work as well :)